# How do you find the closest number in an array while using 2 identifiers?

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array of objects:

```
const arr = [
{num:3,numTwo:1},
{num:5,numTwo:3},
{num:7,numTwo:9},
{num:7,numTwo:3},
{num:8,numTwo:4}
]

const goal = 7
```

I have this code that properly finds the closest number when ONLY accounting for `num`:

```
const closest = arr.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return Math.abs(curr.num - goal) <
      Math.abs(prev.num - goal)
      ? curr
      : prev;
  });
```

It returns `{num:7,numTwo:9}` (because first instance), but I want numTwo to come into play where it returns the object with the lowest `numTwo` if in the case `goal` matches with multiple matching `num`'s, so in this case it should return `{num:7,numTwo:3}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your expression a subtraction and use `||` to involve the comparison of `numTwo` when that subtraction is 0:

```js
const arr = [{num:3,numTwo:1},{num:5,numTwo:3},{num:7,numTwo:9},{num:7,numTwo:3},{num:8,numTwo:4}];
const goal = 7;

const closest = arr.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return (Math.abs(curr.num - goal) - Math.abs(prev.num - goal) 
            || curr.numTwo - prev.numTwo) < 0
        ? curr
        : prev;
});
  
console.log(closest);
```